# data exchange between client server in shiny through javascript

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to send data to server and receive back by a mouse clicking event. Here is a sample code of my program.
.In the first part I have created a javascript function 'mouseclick' where by clicking a circle object the id is sent to server.
And on the server side that input is processed and a set of sample is generated using 'rnorm' function in R.
 Now the output generated by 'rnorm' is sent back to the client.
I want to store this data into the variable 'items' .
The code to receive data back is given below which is accessed by 'Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler'.
Now the problem is, if I print 'items' inside 'Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler' , it shows values received from server.
If I access it outside 'Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler' it shows 'item' variable empty.
How can I store the value to a user defined variable ?

```
//// Javascript code    
<script type="text/javascript">
function mouseclick(d) {
var items = new Array();
Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", d.name);
$(document).ready(function() {
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("testmessage",
function(message) {
for(var i =0; i < message.value.length; i ++){
items.push(message.value[i]);
}
alert(items);
});
});
alert(items); 
}
</script>


########## Server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
output$tres <- renderPrint({
nb <- rnorm(10,  input$mydata+1)
nb
})

observe({
print(input$mydata)
nb <- rnorm(10,  input$mydata+1)
session$sendCustomMessage(type='testmessage', list(value=nb))
})
})
```